# count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable at LINE 428 error in PHP

Tags: php, api, php-curl

Am trying to save some data to an API which but I keep getting this error **count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable at LINE 428**,,, the API am posting data to accepts an array of objects but in my data children variable is throwing the above error..

Please assist?

```
$children = '[{"child_name" => "Mmansa" , "child_dob" => "jdhjdhjd" }]'; 

$data = [
      'quote_id' => $quote,
      'country_residence' => $resd,
      'physical_address' => $physical,
      'children' => $children,
];
```

**Post via Curl**

```
$res = $this->global_Curl($data, 'api/travel/save-policy-meta');
```

**Curl function**

```
 public function global_Curl($data, $url)
    {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, (env('API_ENDPOINT_NGINX_IP') . '/' . $url));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, TRUE); 
        $response = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
        curl_close($ch);
        return $response;
    }
```

**Data required by the API**

```
{
"quote_id":136,
"country_residence":"Japan",
"physical_address":"Tokyo",
"children":[
    {"child_name":"abc","child_dob":"23-05-2015"}
  ]
}
```

Comment: Where is your `count` call?

Comment: You doesnt' need to declare `$children` as string. Works with array and use `json_encode()` to convert array to json.

Comment: @BartFriederichs  Am not using any count call anywhere am just posting the data to the API

Comment: '[{"child_name" => "Mmansa" , "child_dob" => "jdhjdhjd" }]'; probably isn't readable as array for your API , just a string

Comment: @OlegNurutdinov  I converted the array to Json but it still throws the same error

Comment: Edit your question with updates, please.

Comment: Please show Your **LINE 428** and surroundings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your API need JSON request, Which you are sending as a array in `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` and also having one field as invalid JSON string

This string is not a valid JSON

```
'[{"child_name" => "Mmansa" , "child_dob" => "jdhjdhjd" }]'
```

It supposed to be like this

```
'[{"child_name" : "Mmansa" , "child_dob" : "jdhjdhjd" }]'
```

Here no need to write a JSON string, Instead of this you can use [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) method to convert a array to JSON string

Change this

```
$children[] = ["child_name" => "Mmansa" , "child_dob" => "jdhjdhjd"]; 

$data = [
  'quote_id' => $quote,
  'country_residence' => $resd,
  'physical_address' => $physical,
  'children' => $children,
];
```

And try this code

```
public function global_Curl($data, $url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, (env('API_ENDPOINT_NGINX_IP') . '/' . $url));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, TRUE); 
    $response = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
    curl_close($ch);
    return $response;
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation of why they should *try this*.

Comment: @sanu Thanks alot,, it works fine... What if I have another children array,, can I do this:  `$children[] = ["child_name" => "Mmansa" , "child_dob" => "jdhjdhjd"] ["child_name" => "Mmansa" , "child_dob" => "jdhjdhjd"]; `

Comment: @Patweb If you have another children array you have to add in separate line for example

`$children[] = ["child_name" => "child1" , "child_dob" => "dob1"];`

`$children[] = ["child_name" => "child2" , "child_dob" => "dob2"];`


Wish you a happy Coding